# ASP.NET Javascript Timer

Tags: asp.net, javascript

I have a countdown timer in javascript that is called by a code behind using asp.net VB. I cannot find a way to keep track of the time ,.

the problem is., I cannot get the time that elapsed after postback so that the timer would continue ticking,. can you help me please,.?? I would really appreciate it.,

here is my code fragment:

asp.net VB codebehid

```
    on page load{
        If Page.IsPostBack = True Then
            ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(Me.GetType, "timer_script",
           "<script language='javascript'>function mySubmit()</script>")

            ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Me.GetType, "timer_script", 
            "<script>countdown_clock();</script>")
        End If

        If Page.IsPostBack = false Then
            TimerTxtbx.Text = "00:06:10"   'hour:min:sec -> initialize timer
            ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(Me.GetType, "timer_script",
           "<script language='javascript'>function mySubmit()</script>")

            ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Me.GetType, "timer_script", 
            "<script>countdown_clock();</script>")
        End If
    }

    on button click{
        NextBtn.Attributes.Add("onclick", "mySubmit()")   'call a javascript function

        ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Me.GetType, "timer_script", 
        "<script>countdown_clock();</script>")
    }
```

javascript code:

```
function mySubmit()
{
    document.getElementById('TimerTxtbx').removeAttribute('disabled');
}

    function countdown_clock()
{                   
    var current_time;
    current_time = document.getElementById('TimerTxtbx').value;


    var hours = current_time.substring(0,2);
    var minutes = current_time.substring(3,5);
    var seconds = current_time.substring(6,8);  

    var n_seconds;
    var n_minutes = minutes;
    var n_hours = hours;

    if (seconds == 0)
    {
       n_seconds = 59;

       if (minutes == 0)
        {
        n_minutes = 59;
            if (hours == 0){
            alert('Time is up');
            return;
            }
                else{   
                n_hours = hours - 1;
               if (n_hours < 10)
                   n_hours = "0" + n_hours;
                }
            }
        else
        {
            n_minutes = minutes - 1;
            if (n_minutes < 10)
                n_minutes = "0" + n_minutes;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        n_seconds = seconds - 1;
        if (n_seconds < 10)
            n_seconds = "0" + n_seconds;
    }


      document.getElementById('TimerTxtbx').value = n_hours + ':' + n_minutes + ':' + n_seconds;

      setTimeout("countdown_clock()",1000); //function call and delay by 1sec

      document.getElementById('TimerTxtbx').setAttribute('disabled','disabled');
      }//end function
```

Comment: What exactly is the problem you're having, is it keeping the time constant over postbacks?

The code you've put up there works for me the initial page load, just not in postback.

Comment: yes,! that is actually the problem., I cannot get the time that elapsed after postback,. can you please help me.,?

Comment: sorry if i did not elaborate it at the first time i posted my code,. your algorithm and mine are the same (^_^),. you can look again at my post,. I have edited (^_^),.

Comment: You're close, check my updated explanation. I think that should fix things for you, make sure to mark the question as answered if it does.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your problem is that you have to undisable the textbox when you submit, otherwise the text doesn't get tracked in the viewstate.

This code works for me:

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div>
    <asp:TextBox ID="TimerTxtbx" runat="server" />
    <asp:Button runat="server"  OnClientClick="mySubmit()"/>
</div>
</form>
```

With code behind:

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(typeof (Page), "timer_script",
                                           "<script>countdown_clock();</script>");

        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            TimerTxtbx.Text = "00:00:10";
        }
    }
```

Update based on yours:

The problem is that you are setting the OnClientClick property of your button in the Click event handler for your button.

This basically means it won't have any effect until the button is clicked, and then it isn't useful to you.

Set the OnClientClick somewhere like OnInit or Page_Load, or just do it in the aspx like in my example. Does this makes sense to you? When you click the button the OnClientClick property must have already been set.

If you're going to do any ASP.NET stuff, you really want to readup and really get to know the page lifecycle. Starting points:

- http://www.15seconds.com/issue/020102.htm
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx

Comment: thank you so much.,!!! i did it.,!!! wahahahah .,!!! so happy.,!!! i have just put the  "NextBtn.Attributes.Add("onclick", "mySubmit()")" on page load., thank you so much,. i really appreciate it,.!!! i've been woeking on that problem since ages., eheheh ,. thank you again ,.

Comment: No problem, you should click the checkbox next to the answer to mark it as complete.